# SQLAlchemy, query with date interval, filtering by time_start and time_end

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I like to build a query to return elements between the interval `date_start` and `date_finish` filtering a specific time interval like 02AM to 04AM.

```
all_elements = "elements >= date_start and <= date_finish"
all_elements_on_interval = "all_elements >= x.time and <= y.time"
```

ps: it's a first time with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: It looks like you are asking about how to compose a quite basic query with a filter by date or date and time (maybe just by hour, not sure). What exactly is the problem? Did you read the SQLAlchemy documentation on how to write queries and filter data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your column type an `sqlalchemy.DateTime` object, you can run a  pretty simple filter; sqlalchemy uses the python `datetime.datetime()` object.

```
class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'elements'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    dt = Column(DateTime)

date_start = datetime(2017, 10, 27, 2, 0)
date_finish = datetime(2017, 10, 27, 4, 0)

all_elements_on_interval = session.query(Element).filter(and_(Element.dt >= date_start, Element.dt <= date_finish)).all()
```

Don't forget to import datetime and the sqlalchemy and_

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import and_
```